# Word "切り開く" / "きりひらく"

Tags: translation, meaning, words, song-lyrics

I'm translating a song and I have a problem with one part.
I know that きりひらく means "open up" or "clear", but what is the object here? Or maybe it has different meaning in this situation? Full song lyrics if more context is needed: https://mojim.com/usy108340x11x6.htm
And here's the fragment:

> だってふぉーちゅんぜんぶ　輝かせてあげる
>   グレイシー！　スパイシー！　**きりひらく**あたし　勝利の女神!!

Comment: 「ふぉーちゅん」があるから「運命を切り開く」とかですかね・・？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

切り開く (or sometimes 切り拓く) often takes objects like 道を, 未来を, 運命を, 人生を, 展望を, 時代を, 可能性を, and such. 運命を切り開く is a set phrase that means something like "to carve one's destiny".

In this case, the whole lyrics are filled with words like 女神, 未来 and ミラクル, so even without an explicit object, people can safely feel the positive nuance of the verb. I think "move forward" or something similar will do the job.